# jQuery cross domain xmlrpc library

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any other jquery or javascript plugin for support cross domain xmlrpc request.

Already I have tried with 'jquery.xmlrpc' plugin.
https://github.com/maelstrom/jquery-xmlrpc

But it seams not working with cross domain support.

Please advice me.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try easyXDM: http://easyxdm.net/
Has worked for me in the past.